# Uncaught ImagickException: Postscript delegate failed

Tags: php, pdf, centos, ghostscript, imagick

CentOS 7
Apache, PHP 7.4

Simple code:

```
$ofile = 'test.pdf';
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($ofile);
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: Postscript delegate failed `[ghostscript library 9.25] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-16528HfVzp_FNGdCX%d' '-f/tmp/magick-16528LrkMb-C0CmIS' '-f/tmp/magick-165281qaTU7bnOBON'': ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc | ./base/gsicc_manage.c:2261: gsicc_init_iccmanager(): cannot find default icc profile ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_rgb.icc | ./base/gsicc_manage.c:2025: gsicc_set_device_profile(): cannot find device profile **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting. @ error/ghostscript-private.h/InvokeGhostscriptDelegate/171

I try reinstall imagick. But no results...

I try:

```
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/share/ghostscript/lib:/usr/share/ghostscript/iccprofiles:/usr/share/ghostscript/Resource/Init/');
```

but no results...

Please help...

---

DONE!
The problem was in PHP Jail!

Comment: It would be easier to read if the newlines hadn't been eaten but it looks like your installation of Ghostscript is broken: "./base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc". Adding to the $PATH or any other environment variable won't help, you could try adding -I/usr/share/ghostscript/iccprofiles to the command line for Ghostscript so that the iccprofiles get included, and you should check they exist at that location. Also, UPDATE! 9.25 is old and has serious vulnerabilities.

Comment: thanks, but I need use imagic only in php script in browser, not in command line(((